# VBA Consolidation for worksheets with different formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a VBA code that will consolidate 50 sheets in a separate excel workbook. What is causing me trouble is that the sheets have different formatting. I only need 2 items from each sheet but they can be located in different columns, and I want them copied to the same column on the new worksheet.

So for example, the second item I want consolidated can be located between columns B and F.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you were doing this manually how would you locate the values to be copied?  Right now it's difficult to make any real suggestions.

Comment: If the location of the 2 items is inconsistent on the sheets, the code will need a consistent and reliable way to identify them (column header & item name, or item ID, etc)

Comment: `DataColumn = ws.Range("B1:F1").Find(What:="YourString", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column     
wsSummary.Cells(InputRow,InputColumn) = ws.Cells(ExportRow, DataColumn)`